# Store instances of workflow in memory

Tags: c#, .net, workflow-foundation-4

Is there a way in workflow to save the current workflow instance, the variables, path, etc. in memory in a c# .net desktop application?

Is there a way to resume that exact instace?

Comment: Instance no, copy of object probably yes.

Comment: Do you mean you want to persist the current state (including data) of a running workflow instance? If so, have a look at [`SQLWorkflowInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489420(v=vs.110).aspx) and `Bookmarking`. You can write your own [Custom Instance Stores](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee829481(v=vs.110).aspx) if the desktop app doesn't have access to a SqlServer.

Comment: @StuartLC it does have access to sqlserver, but i would rather hold them in memory.

Comment: @StuartLC The thing is, its a UI driven by workflow, so each decision they make could change the path they are on. So at each decision point, i want to copy that exact workflow into a master collection, and when they change the decision point related with that workflow, reload the decision point they had.